# Parameter in Controller is giving null value exception in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am making a text-box with drop down for auto-completing suggestion using jquery and ajax but the error I have found through debugging is that when the debug point comes to the given code it successfully moves to return statement and when comes second time on the same statement it gives an exception that **"Keyword is null"** (Keyword is the alphabet entered by the user in the textbox)

```
var result = (from a in objGameList where
a.GameName.ToLower().StartsWith(keyword.ToLower()) 
select new { a.GameName });
```

Here is the code:

**Index.cs**

````
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#GameName").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({    
                    url: "/Home/Index",    
                    type: "POST",    
                    dataType: "json",    
                    data: { keyword: request.term },   
                    success: function (data) {   
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {    
                            return { label: item.GameName, value: item.GameName };    
                        }))    
                    },    
                    error: function () {    
                        alert('something went wrong !');    
                    }    
                })    
            },   
            messages: {   
                noResults: "", results: ""    
            }    
        });    
    })    
</script>
        
@using (Html.BeginForm())    
{    
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()   
    <div class="form-horizontal">    
        <div class="form-group">    
            <div>       
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GameName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })   
            </div>    
        </div>        
    </div>   
}
```
````

**Controller.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Index(string keyword)
    {
        //This can be replaced with database call.
    
        List<Games> objGameList = new List<Games>(){
            new Games {Id=1,GameName="Cricket" },
            new Games {Id=2,GameName="Football" },
            new Games {Id=3,GameName="Chesh" },
            new Games {Id=4,GameName="VallyBall" },
        };
    
        var result = (from a in objGameList
                        where a.GameName.ToLower().StartsWith(keyword.ToLower())
                        select new { a.GameName });
    
        return Json(result);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce it with provided code. `when comes second time on the same statement` - what do You exacly mean by that? It hits breakpoint inside the controller for the second time without calling AJAX? Or You type and delete a letter, forcing autocomplete to send the same request and the second one does not have any data with it? Which version of the jQuery and jQuery UI are You using? I've used jQuery 1.12.4 and UI 1.12.1 to reproduce with no results.

Comment: There is no `Model` definition in your View...  the following is invalid: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.GameName`

Comment: @HoomanBahreini The controller action shown does not correspond to the view code that is being displayed. The controller action is being called through AJAX and returns JSON.

Comment: @Eatos When i enter the text in textbox the debug point reaches the function in controller, it goes to return statment for the first time successfully when postback to the given statement it gives the mentioned error

Comment: Sorry, if I understand correctly: type "C", controler returns, type "r", controller returns, remove "r", controller throws error? Which version of the libraries? This is happening regardless of text You are typing (with match or not)? With versions I tried if immediately returned from "Cr" to "C" the API is called only 1, not 3 times (it detects that the value did not change from "C"). Maybe Your version works differently?

Comment: i am working on asp.net core mvc.When i enter "c" i need it to show all the text that contains "c" in the drop down and i have tried entering the text in both cases i.e. lower and upper but not working. Also tried it on asp.net mvc

Comment: But what You have entered there right before it stop working? Sorry for asking but I've created empty ASP.NET Core MVC solution, added Your view code (added missing `@Model Games`), controller (adding missing m...) Oh, You know what? Can You show us action which is calling the view?

Comment: While reproducing I made 2 changes in Your code, maybe this is the key... 1) adding this `@Model Games` to make the exaple even compile (I assumed that You just miss that line while copying) 2) add an action to be able to call presented View: `return View(new Games())` but I also assumed that You had to have it to call the view properly. But let us see the calling action from the controller.

Comment: @Eatos I just have entered the letter c and it is not showing any suggestion  when i debug the code then i came to know that the when once the debug point comes to this query in controller it moves to the next return statement and then post back to this statement again and gave the exception that i have mentioned

Comment: @Eatos can you please add the modified code here so that i can better understand your point.Please if its convinient to you

Comment: Yes, sure, I will once returned home.

Comment: So nyc of you I shall be waiting for response

Answer (score 2):

So I made an example from scratch to see if it wouldn't work and... it worked so please follow the example and try to figure out what is different in your aproach. I'll point out every change I made compared to the code fragments You have provided.

I'll start with the new empty project.

```
dotnet new mvc -o test
```

I copy and paste entire `POST` action of Yours into the `HomeController.cs`, fixing imports and generating a missing `Games` model, putting that file into `.\Models\Games.cs`:

```
namespace test.Models
{
    public class Games // changed the default visibility to public
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string GameName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I replaced content of `./Views/Home/Index.cshtml` with Your view (adding at the top of the file the line: `@Model Games` to let the view know about the model so the `@Html.EditorFor()` be able to generate the form control - without it i got an error: `CS1963  An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation`):

So:

```
@model Games
<script type="text/javascript">
...
```

I have putted jQuery imports in `.\Shared\_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
```

and removed reference to any other js file:

```
...
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Lastly I have edited the default action of `HomeController`:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
  return View(new Games()); // added new Games object to be injected as a model for the view.
}
```

At that stage I do not encounter anything what You have described. Although I got an error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.options.messages.results is not a function` but this is something completly different and can be solved by replacing

```
    messages: {
        noResults: "", results: ""
    }
});
```

with this:

```
    messages: {
        noResults: "", results : function(count) {
        return "";
      }
    }
});
```

The solution results in no errors and working mechanism.

Please play around with it, it simply ahould work. All I can come up with is the different library version.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your kindness @Eatos. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataType: "json",
data: { keyword: request.term },
```

You are sending data as JSON like this. That means that there is a single object being sent to the server with a `keyword` property.

When sending JSON objects to the server, you should always create a custom complex object in order for ASP.NET Core to deserialize it properly:

```
public class AutoCompleteViewModel
{
    public string Keyword { get; set; }
}
```

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Index(AutoCompleteViewModel model)
{
    // work with model.Keyword instead
}
```